# Should this noun used in a possessive sense be singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

Consider the following comment in a C++ source file:

```
/* These members are documented with their associated property. */
```

Should the word *property* be singular or plural? Each member is associated with exactly **one** property. However, because there are multiple members, there are multiple properties.

Comment: I guess both are correct because they have different meanings. For instance, when we are refering to everybody's eyes (sorry I don't have a better example), we say `their eyes`; when we are refering to the head, respectively, `their head`.

Comment: Short answer: singular. There's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of your two options, you would use singular otherwise it would not be accurate.

However, it may be clearer to say "Each member is documented with its associated property".  I would suggest it would be even clearer to say "Each member is documented with its **corresponding** property".  **Corresponding** tends to imply a more one-to-one relationship than associated.

[Reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corresponding)
3. associated in a working or other relationship: *a bolt and its corresponding nut.*

Comment: The question is not about rephrasing, though. It's an *A* or *B* case.

Answer (score 0):

If each member had one and only one property, then the singular would be most appropriate.  On the other hand, if one or more members had more than one property, then the plural would be more appropriate.